# Which conjunction should I use before the word that

Tags: conjunctions

The courts remain convinced,__?____,that wearing jeans are not good.

Comment: There is already a subordinator present -- the word "that", which introduces the content clause "that wearing jeans are not good"  You could hardly insert another one, now could you?

Answer (score 1):

This sentence does not need a conjunction, especially if you intended those commas to be there. Instead, I think the sentence should use an adverb. For example, these sentences would work well:

> The courts remain convinced, ***ultimately***, that wearing jeans ***is*** not good.
>
> The courts remain convinced, ***unanimously***, that wearing jeans is not good.

Comment: "**However**" is a good option too, although not a conjunction.